# Silently POST a URL in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to trigger an alarm using a specific URL. 
Alarm script should start/stop/start/off the alarm for 5 seconds. I don't want users to be redirected from the page.

This script should start/stop the alarm (using those special local host URL strings). Would this work?

```php
?php

/* start alarm for 5 seconds */
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/cgi-bin/controller.cgi?target=2&amp;control=1');

/* note to user that alarm is on */
echo 'Alarm started...' "<br>";
echo date('h:i:s') . "<br>";

/* alarm off for 5 seconds */
sleep(5);
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/cgi-bin/controller.cgi?target=2&amp;control=0');

/* alarm on for 5 seconds */
echo date('h:i:s');
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/cgi-bin/controller.cgi?target=2&amp;control=1');

/* alarm off for 5 seconds */

echo file_get_contents('http://localhost/cgi-bin/controller.cgi?target=2&amp;control=0');

?>
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot to add that echo file_get_contents should load this whole XML thing which I don't want to printed on the page.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>http://localhost/cgi-bin/controller.cgi?target=2&amp;control=1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the objective is. But sleeping on the server side will be pretty disruptive to the client.

Comment: I think calling those endpoints from the client side using AJAX would make more sense.

Comment: `Would this work?` Have you tried it? Did it work for you? Did you get an error? Was there a problem? We are here to help you write code when you have debugging problems, not review it and guess if it would work in your environment. No one here can tell if that would run other than it doesn't have syntax errors.

Comment: If you don't want to print the contents of that URL, don't `echo` it…

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you may want to look at clientside ajax post methods (the clientside would be a small amount of Js that would call out to the server side without refreshing the page)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned the best option is to have JavaScript call the end points and handle the timeout. This is simply because calling it from PHP will under normal circumstances cause of delay greater than the sum of all your sleeps before anything in the html page is loaded. Any delay more than a few seconds before the page starts to render generally gas people assume the site is broken and leave or repeatedly hitting the reload button to try to make it work.

In other words, it's a bad UX experience.

Adm: BTW, you can assign the output of file_get_contents to a variable. You don't have to echo it.